# Why is my web scraping code not extracting any content?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am writing up a lit review and trying to us Python Web Scraping the abstracts etc. info about other research on a web.

For example,  I'd like to extract the content of 'Transcript' from this webpage https://cdm20045.contentdm.oclc.org/digital/collection/p20045coll17/id/1414/rec/3 and wrote a Python code, but it seems not working at all and didn't extract anything:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://cdm20045.contentdm.oclc.org/digital/collection/p20045coll17/id/1417/rec/4"
html = requests.get(url,verify=False)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text,'html.parser')
item = soup.find('span', {'data-id': 'itemText'})
print(item)
```

Here is also a screenshot of the inspect, I wanted to extract the text paragraph.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The issue is that while the element you are attempting to target _does_ exist, it only exists after the page is rendered (by javascript).

Hence requesting the page via the requests library and parsing the received html will give you no matches.

Instead what you can do is view the source, figure out the location of the information you are trying to scrape (in this case, your transcript data is located on line 47), and accordingly query for that.

Answer (score 3):

The data you're looking for is stored inside `<script>` tag, so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it. You can use `re`/`json` module to parse it:

```py
import re
import json
import requests

url = "https://cdm20045.contentdm.oclc.org/digital/collection/p20045coll17/id/1414/rec/3"
html_doc = requests.get(url).text

data = re.search(r"window\.__INITIAL_STATE__ = JSON.parse\((.*)\);", html_doc)
data = json.loads(json.loads(data.group(1)))

print(data["item"]["item"]["text"])
```

Prints:

```
This project will examine the economic impact of climate change, and climate change policy, on New Zealand households, families, and individuals. Price outputs and employment indices from Climate Change Commission models will be used with Treasury’s microsimulation model (TAWA) to model the impact on household incomes and expenditure due to different climate change mitigation pathways and policy settings.
```

Comment: Thank you so much Andrej. It worked perfect. Another quick question, I'd also like to extract the content of 'Item Description' i.e. Title, Main topic, Date. I was attempting to add new lines based on your code but failed (sorry, I'm still very new to Python). Please can you help with that as well if you don't mind.

Comment: @tgallavich `data` is a dictionary, so you can use different keys to access the right values. Try to `print(data)` to get the overview whats stored inside the variable.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are unable to extract the data is because it is not 'physically' present inside your DOM. If you inspect the HTML code, you will find that the website is dynamically loaded using JavaScript. What that means in terms of implementation is that you need to find a way to render JavaScript files before parsing the HTML.

One way you can achieve this is by using Selenium, which opens an actual browser and navigates to the targeted URL before returning you the parsed HTML. Here is an implementation example using Python and Selenium:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

TARGET_URL = "https://cdm20045.contentdm.oclc.org/digital/collection/p20045coll17/id/1414/rec/3"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5000)
driver.get(TARGET_URL)

# Wait for the 'Transcript' header (button) to be available and 
# click on it in order to load the content you are targeting
# Note how we are locating the element by its xPath (check explination bellow)
transcript_header = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/button/h2/span[2]')))
transcript_header.click()

# Locate the element by CSS and print its content 
transcript = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#singleItemTranscript')))
print(transcript.text)

driver.quit()
```

### Getting the xPath

On static layouts, if there are multiple elements with the same `class` name and no `id` to specifically identify them, I recommend using xPaths. In order to grab the xPath of an element:

1. Navigate to the website you're targeting
2. Open your browser's developer tools (View > Developer > View source in Chrome)
3. Select the element you are targeting
   [image]
4. Right click on the element > Copy > Copy xPath
   [image]